# Change tab of another app's tabbed dialog box with windows api

Tags: winapi

I am writing code to interact with a tabbed dialog box in an external application. The dialog has two tabs and I wish to inspect a control on the second tab.

When the dialog is opened the second tab and its controls are not visible to Spy++; I assume they are only drawn if the tab is selected.

Is is possible via windows api calls or otherwise to programmatically select the second tab?
I have tried sending a TCM_SETCURSEL to the sysTabControl32 control. This does cause the second tab's caption to be highlighted but the second tab pane itself is not drawn and the controls are still not visible to Spy++

Comment: >> I assume they are only drawn if the tab is selected. In fact, they are only **created** once the tab has been selected for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by simulating Ctrl+Tab keyboard input with `SendInput`:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Dialog Title");
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

KEYBDINPUT tabDown = {VK_TAB, 0};
KEYBDINPUT tabUp = {VK_TAB, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP};
KEYBDINPUT ctrlDown = {VK_CONTROL, 0};
KEYBDINPUT ctrlUp = {VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP};

// ctrl+tab twice
KEYBDINPUT keysequence[] = {ctrlDown, tabDown, tabUp, tabDown, tabUp, ctrlUp};

for (int i=0; i<(sizeof(keysequence)/sizeof(KEYBDINPUT)); i++)
{
  INPUT input;
  input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  input.ki = keysequence[i];
  SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, it states:

[TCM_SETCURSEL message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760612.aspx)

> A tab control does not send a `TCN_SELCHANGING` or `TCN_SELCHANGE` notification code when a tab is selected using this message.

`TCM_SETCURSEL` is intended to be sent by the application that owns the Tab control, so such notifications would be redundant as the app already knows that it is changing the selected tab.

However, since you are sending `TCM_SETCURSEL` to an external process, so you need to send those notifications yourself, which gives the app a chance to react to the selected tab being changed as if the user had selected the target tab by hand, eg:

```
HWND hTabCtrl = ...;
int iTabIndex = ...;

HWND hParent = GetParent(hTabCtrl);

NMHDR nmhdr = {0};
nmhdr.hwndFrom = hTabCtrl;
nmhdr.idFrom = GetDlgCtrlID(hTabCtrl);

nmhdr.code = TCN_SELCHANGING;
if (SendMessage(hParent, WM_NOTIFY, (WPARAM)hTabCtrl, (LPARAM)&nmhdr) == FALSE)
{
    TabCtrl_SetCurSel(hTabCtrl, iTabIndex);

    nmhdr.code = TCN_SELCHANGE;
    SendMessage(hParent, WM_NOTIFY, (WPARAM)hTabCtrl, (LPARAM)&nmhdr);
}
```